# Is there any way to check whether user has recieved the notification recieved from firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a one to one chat app using flutter at client side and firebase as my backend. I use firebase messaging for sending notification to the reciever . I want to show single tick for sent double ticks for delivered and blue ticks for seen same as whatsapp.Is there any way that it could be achieved with firebase and flutter

Comment: There is no firebase API that does that for you. You need to implement it in your code.

Comment: How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. Once the message is sent to firebase, you set the single tick.
2. When the message is received, set the double tick

   _firebaseMessaging.configure(
   onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
   // here you set the double tick
   },
   );
3. In our Widget showing the message you set the blue ticks